# Vue2 V-model on Select with Options built using V-for

Tags: vuejs2

I've been rebuilding some of my website and ran into an issue getting my Select to bind correctly to my Options. The list loads just fine, but the selected value does not get loaded. Here's a reduced snippit of the code I'm trying to run.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <select v-model="activeItem.id">
      <option
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.id"
        :item="item"
        :value="item.id"
      >
        {{item.displayData}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  computed: {
      items(){ 
         return this.$store.state.items;
      },
      activeItem(){ 
         return this.$store.state.activeItem; 
      }
   }
</script>
```

I've searched around the web for answers, but haven't seen one specific to this type of setup. I had it working previously, but it was modelled against specific strings rather than ID's. I'm not sure why it changed. All of my data is dynamic so I can't hard code values or anything. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the data's ids. Nevermind